# We have already had nodejs, why we need nginx or apache?

Tags: node.js, apache, nginx, server

Recently, I set up me blog site which powered by Ghost -- A light weight, fast and static blog framework. I note that Ghost servers on the nodejs, and I needn't to install apache or nginx anymore.

In this way, why we need apache or nginx? I know nginx is famous of it's outstanding performance, but how about nodejs server's performance?

Answer (score -1):

The V8 engine your NodeJS code runs on is supposed to be a Javascript runtime to execute Javascript code, and not perform as a server.

Therefore, it is better to reverse-proxy your NodeJS application through a server such as Nginx.

Moreover, when you require server based features such as load-balancing, caching, max post size, request timeout etc, it is better to use a proper server software that you can configure these settings on than to depend on the language's runtime. You can still do these things in the language's runtime but that will be an overkill.